# Как сделать чтобы при выборе элемента списка менялся текст абзаца?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы при выборе определенного `li`, менялось содержимое `p` на значение `li`

```js
var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select");

var company = document.getElementById("company");

select.onclick = select_company;

function select_company() {
  company.innerHTML = "";
};
```

```html
<p id="company">Выберите компанию</p>

<ul>
  <li class="select">Компания 1</li>
  <li class="select">Компания 2</li>
  <li class="select">Компания 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: id - это уникальный идентификатор, он должен быть только один на странице

Comment: Это исправил, но проблему не решил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас в var select - целая коллекция, поэтому просто так что-то сделать по клику не получится - нужен обход всех элементов этой коллекции:

```js
$('.select').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    $('#company').text($(this).text());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="company">Выберите компанию</p>

<ul>
   <li class="select">Компания 1</li>
   <li class="select">Компания 2</li>
   <li class="select">Компания 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Вариант на чистом `javascript`:

```js
let [select, company] = [
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".select")], document.querySelector("#company")
];

select.map(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  company.innerText = e.target.innerText;
}));
```

```html
<p id="company">Выберите компанию</p>

<ul>
  <li class="select">Компания 1</li>
  <li class="select">Компания 2</li>
  <li class="select">Компания 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: красиво! Вы, случаем, на hexlet'e не учились? )

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо) нет не учился, первый раз слышу)

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя один id назначать сразу нескольким элементам на страницу, вместо него для элементов лучше используйте class. Вариантов реализации достаточно, например:

```html
<p id="company">Выберите компанию</p>

<ul>
   <li class="select">Компания 1</li>
   <li class="select">Компания 2</li>
   <li class="select">Компания 3</li>
</ul>
<script>
var select = document.querySelectorAll('li.select');

var company = document.getElementById("company");

select[0].onclick = function() {
 company.innerHTML = 'Выбрана компания 1';
}

select[1].onclick = function() {
 company.innerHTML = 'Выбрана компания 2';
}

select[2].onclick = function() {
 company.innerHTML = 'Выбрана компания 3';
}
</script>
```